# Get Attribute value from another attribute value in xml file in robot framework

Tags: xml, xpath, robotframework

The below data is xml file.
Here actual,msg,time,type are attributes.

---

```
<properties>    
    <inputs>
        <action actual="0xAB" msg="GENERAL.GROUPING.TAG" time="00:00:00.825" type="SET" />
        <action actual="0xCD" msg="GENERAL.GROUPING.LENGTH" time="00:00:00.826" type="SET" />
        <action actual="0xEF" msg="GENERAL.GROUPING.TRANSACTION_ID" time="00:00:00.826" type="SET" />
        <action actual="0xGH" msg="GENERAL.GROUPING.ORIGINATOR_SYSTEM_TITLE" time="00:00:00.827" type="SET" />
        <action actual="0xIJ" msg="GENERAL.GROUPING.VALUE" time="00:00:00.827" type="SET" />
        <action actual="0xKL" msg="GENERAL.GROUPING.TITLE.LENGTH" time="00:00:00.827" type="SET" />
        <action actual="0xMN" msg="GENERAL.GROUPING.TITLE.VALUE" time="00:00:00.828" type="SET" />
        <action actual="0xOP" msg="GENERAL.GROUPING.DATE" time="00:00:00.828" type="SET" />
    </inputs>
</properties>
```

---

I want to return attribute value of `actual="0xAB"` when attribute `msg="GENERAL.GROUPING.TAG"`.
So depending on attribute 'msg' value I want to print attribute 'actual' value
Kindly help in this issue with example.

Comment: What did you try so far, can you add it to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this XPath-1.0 expression:

```
//action[@msg='GENERAL.GROUPING.TAG']/@actual
```

It returns the attribute value `0xAB`.

Comment: @priyas instead of thanks you could have accepted the answer by clicking on the hollow tick right beside the answer

Comment: i clicked on hollow tick